# How to change mvc razor value according to onClick()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, button, onclick

I'm currently thinking of a layout where I can utilize the value from the razor value from onclick but I don't think I am doing it right. Does this code make sense and if it isn't what are some ways around it?

```
@model ICollection<User>
@{
   int id = 0;
}

@foreach (var i in Model) {
   <button onclick = @{id = i.id} changeStatus(@i.id)> Test </button>
}

<div class="popup" style="display: none;">
     <form method=post>
          <input style="hidden" name="id" value="@id" />
          <input type="submit" value="submit" />
     </form>
</div>

<script>
    function changeStatus(id) {
        $('.popup').show();
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Razor variables are server side so they cannot be accessed on the client side. I would update the hidden field's value using jquery.

```
@foreach (var i in Model) {
   <button onclick ="changeStatus(@i.id)"> Test </button>
}

<div class="popup" style="display: none;">
     <form method="post">
          <input type="hidden" id="userID" value="" />
          <input type="submit" value="submit" />
     </form>
</div>

<script>
    function changeStatus(id) {
        $('.popup').show();
        $("#userID").val(id);
     }
</script>
```